# using hyperref package when have only one appendix

Tags: hyperref, appendices

I would like to have a text as "... (see Appendix)" where the word "Appendix" is a crossref and I have only one appendix. In the name of Appendix section, I want it to be shown as "Appendix: Appendix title".
How can I get that?

I've tried the command `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` but it gave the referenced name back to the last section before the Appendix, e.g., "... (see Section V)" if I use [see + autoref] or "... (see Appendix V)" if I use [see + Appendix + ref].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply define a `\label{appendix}` at the appendix and use `\hyperref[appendix]{see Appendix}` to refer to it.